# Is storing project configuration in environment variables a bad practice?

Tags: python

Some background first:
i am currently testing a class that sends a GET request with a configurable url, which is built like this

```
url = f"{os.environ["TARGET_URL"]}/api/etc"
```

For normal operation, my `TARGET_URL` environment variable is set at project startup from a .env file and everything works. When testing locally, everything is still fine, tests passes and everyone is happy. My issue arose when I discovered that my Drone CI server failed to complete the project's build because the `TARGET_URL` environment variable wasn't found.

After some digging I found out that I had the wrong (dumb) idea that environment variables were reset at every project/test startup, and I basically was using my production environment variable all this time (even during tests) because it was set at first project startup.

From this story comes my question: *given that environment variables are kept between executions, would storing configurations in them result in a bad practice? Is there an equally convenient alternative (no global objects and access from everywhere in the code) that can be used instead?*

Comment: No, it's commonly viewed as good practice, see https://12factor.net/config for example.

Comment: Your story is not clear. On the one hand an environment variable wasn't found (why?) but at the same time it was always the same value? It just sounds like you didn't configure things properly.

Comment: so the issue was that when running the tests locally, the environment variable was set because I had run the project before. When building the server remotely, given that my .env files are not committed for security reasons, no environment variable was loaded. Discovering that my tests were using production environment variables meant that there could be edge cases where they would pass only because the variables were already there

Comment: So are your tests meant to be able to run without any environment variables?

Comment: my environment variables shouldn't be polluted with production values, see my answer to know what I came up with if you are interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables stored in config files or .env files is not a bad practice.

However, it is recommended that you use a key vault such as [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/key-vault/) or [AWS Key Management System](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) for production deployments.

This way you further remove the keys away from your server (if env files) as well as code (if it is in config files)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the quick responses, here's a bit of what-happened-next:

environment variables stay loaded after the first initialization, so I needed a way to test my code after loading only the variables I needed, with values that were expected. This would allow me to keep using environment variables loaded from a .env file and keep building my project remotely, where no .env files are present.

The solution was to add a pytest plugin called pytest-dotenv, which when properly configured would allow me to overwrite every variable in my .env files with a custom variable from another file (.env.test in my case). I filled the .env.test file with all the variables found in the .env file, and assigned empty values to each of them. 
This allowed my tests to run ensuring no weird edge cases are missed because something had the wrong value.

example .env file

```
TARGET_URL="http://my.api.dev
```

example .env.test file

```
TARGET_URL=
```

pytest.ini configuration

```
[pytest]
env_override_existing_values = 1
env_files =
    .env.test
```